# Running Java Application on Openshift

Tags: java, server, openshift, telegram-bot

I have a simple java application, Telegram bot, that i want run constantly on Openshift cloud. How can i do it? I know that there isn't a direct way to run the main of a java application of a server but i know that is possible but how?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Check out the Java source to image (S2I) container image that ships with OpenShift: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_middleware_for_openshift/3/html-single/red_hat_java_s2i_for_openshift/